# How to copy & paste text node in XML

Tags: xml

I have an XML file where I want to copy a text node from one location and paste it to a text node in different location.

Below is the XML file I want to do manipulation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
    <installObj uniqueObjects="2822">
        <object class="Installer" ">
            <visualChildren>
                <object class="InstallSet">
                    <installchildrenMain>
                        <object class="InstallBundle1">
                            <property name="ruleExpression">
                                <string><!***[CDATA[I Need a VALUE!]]***>
                                </string>
                            </property>
                            <property name="bundleName">
                                <string><![CDATA[Australia]]></string>
                            </property>
                            <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                <object class="CompareVariable">
                                    **
                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                        <string><!***[CDATA[CIAV819]]***>
                                        </string>
                                    </property>
                                    **
                                </object>
                            </rules>
                            <installChildren>
                                <object class="InstallComponent1">
                                    <property name="ruleExpression">
                                        <string><!***[CDATA[CIAV962***]]>
                                        </string>
                                    </property>
                                    <property name="componentName">
                                        <string><![CDATA[AUST]]></string>
                                    </property>
                                    <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                        <object class="CompareVariable">
                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                                <string><!***[CDATA[CIAV962]***]>
                                                </string>
                                            </property>
                                        </object>
                                    </rules>
                                    <installChildren>
                                        <object class="InstallDirCont">
                                            <property name="ruleExpression">
                                                <string><![***CDATA[CIAV100 || CIAV503]***]>
                                                </string>
                                            </property>
                                            <rules logicalOperation="OR">
                                                <object class="CompareVariable1">
                                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                                        <string><***![CDATA[CIAV100]***]></string>
                                                    </property>
                                                </object>
                                                <object class="CompareVariable2">
                                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                                        <string><***![CDATA[CIAV503]***]></string>
                                                    </property>
                                                </object>
                                            </rules>
                                        </object>
                                    </installChildren>
                                </object>
                                #end of installComponent1
                                <object class="InstallComponent2">
                                    ======
                                    Same as above (Install Component1)
                                    =====
                                </object>
                                #end of installComponent2
                            </installchildren>
                        </object>
                        #installBundle1
                        <object class="InstallBundle2">
                            ====
                            Same structure as InstallBundle1
                            ====
                        </object>
                        #installBundle2
                    </installchildrenMain>
                </object>
                # End of InstallSet
            </visualChildren>
            # end of visualchildren
        </object>
        # end of Installer
    </installObj>
    <restorationObjects count="0" />
</Main>
```

Now what I want to do here is :

1. Copy "CIAV819" text node value of  from Object class InstallBundle1 - object class CompareVariable and paste it to text node of  of object class InstallBundle1 just before InstallChildrenMain
2. Copy "CIAV962" text node value of  from Object class InstallComponent1 - object class CompareVariable and paste it to text node of  of object class InstallComponent1 just before InstallChildren
3. Copy "CIAV100" text node value of  from Object class InstallDirCont - object class CompareVariable1 and add operand "||" and also copy "CIAV503" text node value from Object class InstallDirCont - object class CompareVariable2 and paste it to text node of  of object class InstallDirCont just before InstallChildren.

I know this looks bit tidious but I need this fix. I am totally new to xml and PHP
Thanks a ton for any help.

Also below is the PHP code that I am using here to manipulate this xml file:

```
<?php

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc ->load('HR92_latest.iap_xml');


#$x = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('/InstallAnywhere_Deployment_Project/installationObjects[1]/object[1]/visualChildren[1]/object[1]/installChildren[1]/object[1]/rules[1]/object[1]/property[8]');
$x = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('//property[@name]');


var_dump ($x);
foreach ($x as $string) {
    echo $string->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

But this code is returning o/p:

object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}

Basically I am trying here to first find the xpath and then the text node's value but it is failing.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

---

10/17/2013 - updated question

@hielsnoppe :I am finding limitations on using DOMDocument. Hence I thought of using your  xslt code. ANd it almost worked but when running on command prompt it displays output as shown below:

```
<object class="InstallComponent1" objectID="03fe9">
            <property><string>CIAV4</string></property>
                <property name="componentName">
                        <string>BA, NT db2</string>
                </property>
                <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                        <object class="CompareVariable" objectID="0304">
                        <property name="ruleId">
                                        <string>CIAV4</string>
                                </property>
                        </object>
                </rules>
                <installChildren>
                        <object class="InstallDirCont" objectID="03005">
                            <property><string>CIAV50 || CIAV60</string></property>
                                <rules logicalOperation="OR">
                                        <object class="CompareVariable">
                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                                <string>CIAV50</string>
                                            </property>
                                        </object>
                                        <object class="CompareVariable">
                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                                <string>CIAV60</string>
                                            </property>
                                        </object>
                                </rules>
                    </object>
                </installChildren>
```

I mean the output is showing as:

```
<object class="InstallComponent1" objectID="03fe9">
                <property><string>CIAV962</string></property>
```

instead of

```
<object class="InstallComponent1" objectID="03fe9">
                <property name="ruleExpression"><string><![CDATA[CIAV962]]</string></property>
```

and when I open the xml file it is still showing rule expression field blank!!

Please help I am very close to solution :) Thanks!!

---

10/18/2013 - updated

Do i have to add the nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE? in the template match for rule expression?

Comment: copy-paste is something you do in a text editor. Since you probably aren't asking about that: o do you want to duplicate a node and insert it somewhere else, or do you want to relocate a node?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans :Hi Mike, Thanks for quick reply. I don't want to do this manually through xml editor. I am trying to automate this process. So i want to duplicate a node and insert it somewhere else.

Comment: Please see my updated answer and tell me, whether I got the copy-paste locations right. They are not completely clear to me from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I assume the input file looks like so but without the comments. in all solutions you might have to adjust the XPath selectors to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
    <installObj uniqueObjects="2822">
        <object class="Installer">
            <visualChildren>
                <object class="InstallSet">
                    <installchildrenMain>
                        <object class="InstallBundle1">
                            <property name="ruleExpression">
                                <string /><!-- PASTE1 -->
                            </property>
                            <property name="bundleName">
                                <string><![CDATA[Australia]]></string>
                            </property>
                            <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                <object class="CompareVariable">
                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                        <string><![CDATA[CIAV819]]></string><!-- COPY1 -->
                                    </property>
                                </object>
                            </rules>
                            <installChildren>
                                <object class="InstallComponent1">
                                    <property name="ruleExpression">
                                        <string /><!-- PASTE2 -->
                                    </property>    
                                    <property name="componentName">
                                        <string><![CDATA[AUST]]></string>
                                    </property>
                                    <rules logicalOperation="AND">
                                        <object class="CompareVariable">
                                            <property name="ruleId">
                                                <string><![CDATA[CIAV962]]></string><!-- COPY2 -->
                                            </property>
                                        </object>
                                    </rules>
                                    <installChildren>
                                        <object class="InstallDirCont">
                                            <property name="ruleExpression">
                                                <string /><!-- PASTE3 -->
                                            </property>
                                            <rules logicalOperation="OR">
                                                <object class="CompareVariable1">
                                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                                        <string><![CDATA[CIAV100]]></string><!-- COPY3.1 -->
                                                    </property>
                                                </object>
                                                <object class="CompareVariable2">
                                                    <property name="ruleId">
                                                        <string><![CDATA[CIAV503]]></string><!-- COPY3.2 -->
                                                    </property>
                                                </object>
                                            </rules>
                                        </object>
                                    </installChildren>
                                </object><!-- end of installComponent1 -->
                                <object class="InstallComponent2" >
                                    <!--
                                    Same as above (Install Component1)
                                    -->
                                </object><!-- end of installComponent2 -->
                            </installChildren>   
                        </object><!-- end of installBundle1 -->
                        <object class="InstallBundle2" >
                            <!--
                            Same structure as InstallBundle1
                            -->
                        </object><!-- end of installBundle2 -->
                    </installchildrenMain>
                </object><!-- end of InstallSet -->
            </visualChildren><!-- end of visualChildren -->
        </object><!-- end of Installer -->
    </installObj>
    <restorationObjects count="0"/>
</Main>
```

If the logic has to be done in PHP, try using [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead of `getElementsByTagName()` to loop over the respective PASTE locations and pull in the data from the corresponding COPY locations. I will not elaborate on this because I prefer the XSLT solution below.

```
<?php

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('HR92_latest.iap_xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);
$paste1 = $xpath->query('//object[starts-with(@class, 'InstallBundle')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']');
$paste2 = $xpath->query('//installChildren/object[starts-with(@class, 'InstallComponent')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']');
$paste3 = $xpath->query('//installChildren/object/installChildren/object[@class='InstallDirCont']/property[@name='ruleExpression']');

foreach ($paste1 as $p) {
    // find corresponding COPY location and pull in the data
}
foreach ($paste2 as $p) {
    // find corresponding COPY location and pull in the data
}
foreach ($paste3 as $p) {
    // find corresponding COPY locations and pull in the data
}
```

Using [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/standards/xml/transformation) I suggest to apply the following transformation saved as `pick_a_meaningful_name.xslt` to your XML document the form of the example above to produce the wanted result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="string" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//object[starts-with(@class, 'InstallBundle')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../rules/object/property/string" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//installChildren/object[starts-with(@class, 'InstallComponent')]/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../rules/object/property/string" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//installChildren/object/installChildren/object[@class='InstallDirCont']/property[@name='ruleExpression']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <string>
            <xsl:for-each select="../rules[@logicalOperation='OR']/object">
                <xsl:value-of select="./property/string" />
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; count(../object)"><xsl:value-of select="' || '" /></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

A minimal example of PHP code to do this might use [`XSLTProcessor`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php) and look like this:

```
<?php

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('HR92_latest.iap_xml');
$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->load('pick_a_meaningful_name.xslt');

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsldoc);
$result = $xslt->transformToDoc($xmldoc);

$result->save('HR92_latest.iap_xml');   // writes result to original file
echo $result->saveXML();                // echoes result
```